# Loop over paragraphs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML stored in a variable which looks like this:

```
<p>Cras eget massa posuere, faucibus tortor eu, suscipit nibh. Pellentesque vitae augue diam. Duis vel placerat massa. Nam vitae consequat odio, id tempus lorem. Aliquam scelerisque odio eget eleifend pulvinar. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur ultricies porttitor elementum.</p>
<p>Suspendisse bibendum condimentum convallis. Mauris suscipit, felis eget sollicitudin fringilla, ante justo gravida eros, nec finibus quam ex vitae neque. Sed eget sapien porttitor, tristique elit eu, malesuada erat.</p>
```

I want read through all the p tags and convert it into an array of innerText of the para tags so that it looks like below:

```
["Cras eget massa posuere, faucibus tortor eu, suscipit nibh. Pellentesque vitae augue diam. Duis vel placerat massa. Nam vitae consequat odio, id tempus lorem. Aliquam scelerisque odio eget eleifend pulvinar. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur ultricies porttitor elementum.", "Suspendisse bibendum condimentum convallis. Mauris suscipit, felis eget sollicitudin fringilla, ante justo gravida eros, nec finibus quam ex vitae neque. Sed eget sapien porttitor, tristique elit eu, malesuada erat."]
```

I don't know how to loop over these P tags. Any help is appreciated. I should be able to use forEach but I don't know how.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: My challenge is that the original html data is not actually in DOM, but is contained in a variable. So, I think I can't used document.get...

Comment: so use .find().

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question to *include* that detail, and any other details that are also relevant. Remember: we know nothing of what you're doing except what you show in your question. Help us to help you, post your "*[mcve]*" code.

Comment: Please also post the variable..you should have said that earlier :)

Comment: `yourArray.forEach(item => { console.log(item); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an artificial container, fill its `innerHTML` with your html from the variable and then use `getElementsByTagName()`.

```
let html = `<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>`;
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
let paragraphs = div.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    console.log(paragraphs[i].innerText) // Will print the content of each paragraph
}
```